# Python Email Size is way bigger than the zip file using smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

So I have the following code for sending email with a zip attachment using smtplib. But the issue is that I am getting an error for exceeding the limit size but the zip file is only 500KB but when I print the total size of the message at the end i see 35MB !!. Any help in understanding this is greatly appreciated ! Thanks

```
zf = open(newZip+".zip","rb")

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = os.environ['EMAIL_USER']
msg['To'] = email
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
msg['Subject'] = "Results - "+email
msg.attach (MIMEText("textMessage"))

part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(zf.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+newZip+".zip")
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(os.environ['EMAIL_USER'], os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD'])
server.sendmail(os.environ['EMAIL_USER'], email, str(msg))

max_limit_in_bytes = int( server.esmtp_features['size'] )
print(max_limit_in_bytes)
print("***********")

server.close()
```

Comment: That's the size limit that you printed out, not the size of your message.

Comment: Oh really! Would you know how to get the real size?

Comment: Can you please put the error you're getting in your question, including the stack trace?

Comment: @Cyborg_Patrick I suppose that `len(str(msg))` is what you're looking for.